# How do I add numbered footnotes on every page?

Tags: footnotes

I wan to be able adding numbered footnotes for some words in my documents, but displaying them on the same page and not at the end of the document. Ho do I do that?

Comment: So you want to be able to specify a footnote that will be attached to _every_ occurrence of a given word in your document, and will appear on every page where the word does? Should all these footnotes have different numbers?

Comment: This strikes me as something of a bad idea. If your document is meant to be read from beginning to end, then your readers should see the footnote at the first occurrence, and be set from there. If your document is more of a random-access reference, then you should probably include these terms in some sort of glossary.

Comment: @David @Novelocrat sorry I didn't mean for a given word whenever the word is occurred.. Just for a specific word, on that page only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your edited question correctly, you're asking how to attach a footnote to a word and have the footnote display on the same page as the word. (Right?) The first thing I would say is that LaTeX generally does this by default, if you use the `\footnote{}` command.  That is, writing the following in your LaTeX source

```
This is some text with a word\footnote{the footnote is attached to "word"}
and some more words
```

will produce a footnote that displays at the bottom of the page on which `word` appears.

If your footnotes are appearing at the end of the document instead, there must be some package or class you're using which causes that behavior. It may have an option to switch between footnotes and endnotes, but I couldn't tell you what that might be unless you provide more information (namely, your document preamble).

Comment: Right :D That's what I was looking for :)

Comment: Ah, well, `\footnote` is pretty basic so I think we all figured you were asking something more sophisticated. You'll probably get better answers in the future if you mention your experience level in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You could define a macro for each term that you want to present this way, as follows:

```
\newcommand{\myword}{myword\footnote{stuff about myword}}
```

And whenever you would write `myword`, you write `\myword` instead.

Note that this has a slight capitalization issue, in that its case is fixed, regardless of use at the beginning of a sentence.

Please take my comment about this being a bad idea to heart, though.